# Gapped data issues in highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm having an issue with Highcharts which is not actually the framework's fault, but rather mine. The data I want to plot may have gaps sometimes in the middle of it, and when trying to plot the points the framework doesn't consider the density of the points and link the gaps when, in my case, it's not supposed to. As you can see in the image below the purple serie wasn't supposed to be linked, but rather leave a gap around 16:00 and 08:00.

One other problem that I face because of the gaps I have is that my chart is many times unproportional like in the image shown below where November takes 1/4 of the chart area, while the other months take the rest of the space. Also between August and September the space is larger than the other monthly intervals.

Last but not least there's finally the issue that I set my chart's X Axis accordingly to a date picker I have on my webpage and I'd love it to start and end at the dates picked, but it instead starts and ends at where the points start and end. I'm setting my limits like this:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',

    min: min,

    max: max,

    minRange: $scope.minRange || Time.MINUTE,

    events: {
         afterSetExtremes: onLazyLoad
    }
}
```

[You can see the gap linking points problem over here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pOHB.png)

[The unproportional chart problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxALM.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5vsN.png This is the image for the last problem

Comment: Without code or sample data to work with all I can offer is to check out the API docs on `connectNulls`: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.connectNulls

Comment: I dont have any null points, what I have is data like: [01:01, 200], [01:02,250], [01:03, 240], but then out of a sudden it may jump like: [01:20, 210]

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to create a series for each group of points and assign the same color to those series that are of the same "kind". There is no built-in mechanism for highcharts to know that you want points A, B, C, and D linked with a line but not D to E.  You can fake this with multiple series but only show one in the legend to be the master for all the series of a "kind" such that you can click on the legend to hide/show.